# How can i make a formula to determine payment types

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-docs, google-sheets-arrayformula, google

I am having trouble nesting and using multiple criteria.  I want a column to determine if payment type was CASH, CHECK or WAITING depending on if the cells for Check# and Payment are containing data.

I have attached my shared Google Sheets files here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lG31qsy8s97OYnrBIK6k3RVR5s1UoxuqntFBJW3_b34/edit?usp=sharing

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFs(and(B2="",C2=""),"WAITING",B2<>"","CHECK",C2<>"","CASH")
```

Comment: This works!!! Now is there a way to expand on this, in order for CHECK to appear you have to have Data entered in both Check # and Payment columns, The other two seem to function as i was expecting but i would prefer as a bit of Error checking to have both cells entered in order for Payment type to display CHECK.

Comment: As soon as you enter B2 Check number it changes result to CHECK, when i want it to be B2 AND C2 in order to output result of CHECK.  I can use it as is, but i am curious how to achieve what i am looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: try: =IFs(and(B2="",C2=""),"WAITING",C2="","",and( B2<>"", C2>0),"CHECK",C2<>"","CASH")

Comment: Your AMAZING! exactly what i had been trying to get! I would have never been able to get this!